Почему отклонили мою тревогу "не является ответом" на очевидном "не ответе"?
Во время проверки, если ответ не является ответом ставлю тревогу, так как есть эта функция, и не раз читала, что надо это делать.
Вчера вне проверки поставила тревогу на ответ, который не был ответом, и тревога была отклоненна

Отклонённая - тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить
модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства


Данный ответ сейчас удалили, вопрос тоже.
Мой вопрос - это ошибка, того кто отклонил тревогу, или изменились правила?

Это и ответом не было. Автор написал по типу "Спасибо мне большое, всё решил". Как такое можно оставить в качестве ответа? Нормальная у вас была тревога

Значит, невнимательность проверяющего. У меня та же тревога была отмечена как полезная

@Chaos_Sower, благодарю за информацию, что ваша тревога "по тому же ответу" была принята полезной. Теперь вообще не понятно, и хотелось бы ответа от того, кто отклонил.

Мне это тоже непонятно, тоже сталкивался с таким пару раз. Я тыкаю в «не является ответом» с расчётом на то, что ответ попадёт в очередь проверок к другим участникам, а иногда внезапно модераторы зачем-то появляются

@Chaos_Sower это не совсем так работает. Тревога считается полезной, если модератор что-то сделал, пока обрабатывал тревогу и отклонённой, если не сделал ничего. Да, тревога была "нормальной", но конкретно в тот конкретный момент я принял решение не делать с ответом ничего, поэтому и отклонил.

"Данный ответ сейчас удалили" - при этом удалил @aepot, перед этим отменив несколько тревог на этом ответе (мою тоже))

@aepot, вижу, что вопрос уже улажен :) Лишь скажу, что в таких случаях лучше пропустить тревогу (чтобы она не пропадала из очереди), нежели её отклонять. Пройдёт как раз достаточно времени на то, чтобы автор исправил ответ, пока она пробудет в очереди

Кстати, вопрос тоже удалён (автором)

@Зонтик, как вы думаете, насколько это верно удалять вопросы на мете, которые "не актуальны", как например этот. То есть тему изжевали, и она касалась конкретного случая, а теперь висит там в ленте...Если я удалю вопрос, а нем есть много комментариев, ответ...это не совсем верно? Я удаляла пару раз вопросы свои, когда я получала достаточно быстрый ответ(при 3 просмотров что то такое...то есть свежий совсем), и не видела надобности, чтоб он висел тут дальше. А вот тут как бы, не знаю...что скажете?

Он не "общий", чтоб был полезен кому то еще...

@aepot, если я удалю данный вопрос - это не будет считаться "вандализмом" (где то в справке видела это выражение)?

@Dev18 не надо удалять. Как минимум ответ модератора может кому-то потом пригодиться

@Зонтик, а как его можно "спрятать" с правой панели, основного сайта // я так поняла +3 голоса и сразу туда попадает

@Dev18 не надо прятать. Вот появиться более важная тема — дык сама спрячется. А пока чем больше людей прочитают ответ модератора, тем лучше

@Dev18 Насчёт попадания в "обусждаемое": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/what-criteria-are-used-to-select-the-links-that-appear-in-the-community-bulletin

да, благодарю, читала (правда не помню где)

Я отклонил тревогу, ответ был свежий, поэтому я дал время автору ответа дооформить его в соотвествии с комментариями под ответом. Когда пришла повторная тревога спустя какое-то время, я удалил ответ учитывая его уже невосполнимый отрицательный рейтинг.
В целом, не стоит звать модераторов удалять ответы, когда ещё есть шанс, что автор отреагирует и поправит ответ.
Для немедленной реакции на качество ответа есть голосование "против". А для тех, у кого достаточно репутации, есть голосование за удаление. Пользуйтесь!
Тревоги безотлагательно стоит использовать на ответах, где модератор должен прямо сейчас явиться и что-то с этим ответом сделать: удалить ответ, забанить автора ответа и т.д. Устанавливая тревогу, ответьте себе на вопрос, что именно вы хотите прямо сейчас от модератора, что не смогли бы сделать другие участники сообщества, не имеющие прав модератора.

Устанавливая тревогу, ответьте себе на вопрос, что именно вы хотите прямо сейчас от модератора, что не смогли бы сделать другие участники сообщества, не имеющие прав модератора => именно это я и сделала, и мой ответ был прост, на момент "тревоги" было -3, прошло достаточно времени даже на комментарии Nowhere Man уже было 2+ или более...автор даже дал и другой какой то ответ, то есть он видел "предупреждения" и не изменил ничего. Я как раз таки увидела его "другой" ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/943005 поняла, что предыдущий он менять не собирается поставила тревогу.

В данной ситуации никто не звал модератора. Почему модератор вообще явился?

Спасибо что пояснили мотивацию отклонения. Но если уж ожидать, что участник поправит ответ - так уж подождите пока он это сделает, а потом тревогу отклоняйте. А то совсем некрасиво выходит )

@Kromster в этом есть смысл, принял к сведению.

@andreymal вы о чём? о том что я пришёл на мету и рискнул что-то написать, или о чём именно? Вообще при появлении вопроса на Мете у всех модераторов появляется уведомление об этом в обязательном порядке. Так что сюда, считайте, меня RU.SO.Meta позвала.

@aepot я про тревогу, которая «способ привлечь внимание сообщества», а вовсе не модератора

@aepot, он говорит о "механизме", почему данная тревога не попадает "в очередь", а рассматривается модератором

@andreymal тревоги как раз используются для того, чтобы уведомить команду модераторов о необходимости вмешательства, или я что-то упускаю?

@aepot чтобы отправить сообщение в очередь проверок без какого-либо участия модераторов ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

я точно помню, что где то читала, что "эти-(не ответ)..." тревоги попадают в "очередь"

и именно тут у меня вчера и возник вопрос. Я как бы поняла, что модератор отклонил. и подумала, значит когда НЕ проверка, механизм другой (?)

@andreymal мы обрабатываем все тревоги по мере возможности сразу. В редких случаях ненадолго откладываем. Мотивацию отметки тревогой я услышал, обсудим с командой, спасибо.

Кстати, в английской справке есть фраза, которой нет в русской: «Moderators may step in to handle flags that aren't handled by ordinary members of the site or the system.». Из чего я подозреваю, что обрабатывать такие тревоги сразу не надо

@andreymal но учтите, что у нас нет различий между тревогами на которые вы хотите действий от модератора и тревогами, где вы не хотите действий модератора. Все тревоги в общей куче. К тому же даже если ответ был удалён сообществом или автором, некоторые типы тревог не снимаются автоматом, а продолжают висеть до момента, пока модератор вручную отметит тревогу как решённую. Навскидку сейчас не скажу, какие именно.

@aepot я подозревал что движок кривой(

@andreymal а я подозревал, что модератора могут ругать за то что он не реагирует на тревоги, но не подозревал, что будут ругать за то что реагировал. :)

@Dev18 я ответил на ваш вопрос, или ещё чем-то помочь?

ещё чем-то помочь? => ваша улыбка))) и ваше хорошее настроение, благодарю вас за вложенный труд.

@Dev18 не за что. Извините, что так вышло.

"поэтому я дал время автору ответа дооформить его" Звучит немного странно. Я бы удалил сразу, автор может и второй ответ запостить если одумается.
